# NodeJS could not read [Object] in JSON data

Tags: node.js, json

I have data as a JSON format

```
{"mac":"f008d155b4fe","deviceClass":["iBeacon","eddystone"],"model":"iBeacon","lastSeen":"1637655820","bevent":{"event":"update"},"rssi":{"last":-84},"beacons":[{"ibeacon":{"uuid":"783a69707094d0863b4a9bf94e555241","major":816,"minor":6,"power":0},"eddystone":{"power":0}}],"sensors":{"temperatureC":18,"voltage":3.299999952316284},"stats":{"uptime":"710","adv_cnt":"24","frame_cnt":7}},
        {"mac":"a0e6f8515eff","deviceClass":["arubaTag"],"firmware":{"bankA":"1.2-15"},"assetId":"0000-0000-0000","lastSeen":"1637655821","bevent":{"event":"update"},"rssi":{"last":-69},"sensors":{"battery":83},"stats":{"uptime":"82350","frame_cnt":3},"vendorName":"Aruba"}
```

[image]

I can print data from the level 1 but I could not print data in another level from JSON
I would like to print value from beacons: [ [Object] ],
Please give me a hints thank you

here is my code

```
const data = [
        {"mac":"f008d155b4fe","deviceClass":["iBeacon","eddystone"],"model":"iBeacon","lastSeen":"1637655820","bevent":{"event":"update"},"rssi":{"last":-84},"beacons":[{"ibeacon":{"uuid":"783a69707094d0863b4a9bf94e555241","major":816,"minor":6,"power":0},"eddystone":{"power":0}}],"sensors":{"temperatureC":18,"voltage":3.299999952316284},"stats":{"uptime":"710","adv_cnt":"24","frame_cnt":7}},
        {"mac":"a0e6f8515eff","deviceClass":["arubaTag"],"firmware":{"bankA":"1.2-15"},"assetId":"0000-0000-0000","lastSeen":"1637655821","bevent":{"event":"update"},"rssi":{"last":-69},"sensors":{"battery":83},"stats":{"uptime":"82350","frame_cnt":3},"vendorName":"Aruba"}
  ];
  
  const arr1 = data.filter(d => d.mac == "f008d155b4fe");
  console.log('arr1', arr1);
  for (k in arr1.beacons) {
    console.log(k, ":", arr1.beacons[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are close to the solution, but `arr1` is an array, so it doesn't have a 'beacon' property. Use the following instead:

```
    const data = [
        {"mac":"f008d155b4fe","deviceClass":["iBeacon","eddystone"],"model":"iBeacon","lastSeen":"1637655820","bevent":{"event":"update"},"rssi":{"last":-84},"beacons":[{"ibeacon":{"uuid":"7$
        {"mac":"a0e6f8515eff","deviceClass":["arubaTag"],"firmware":{"bankA":"1.2-15"},"assetId":"0000-0000-0000","lastSeen":"1637655821","bevent":{"event":"update"},"rssi":{"last":-69},"sen$
  ];

  const arr1 = data.filter(d => d.mac == "f008d155b4fe");
  console.log('arr1', arr1);
  for (k of arr1) {
    console.log(k.beacons);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, I made it all an object and now you can access the beacons by doing `newData.devices[0].beacons[0].(property)`

```
const newData = {"devices": [{"mac":"f008d155b4fe","deviceClass":["iBeacon","eddystone"],"model":"iBeacon","lastSeen":"1637655820","bevent":{"event":"update"},"rssi":{"last":-84},"beacons":[{"ibeacon":{"uuid":"783a69707094d0863b4a9bf94e555241","major":816,"minor":6,"power":0},"eddystone":{"power":0}}],"sensors":{"temperatureC":18,"voltage":3.299999952316284},"stats":{"uptime":"710","adv_cnt":"24","frame_cnt":7}},         {"mac":"a0e6f8515eff","deviceClass":["arubaTag"],"firmware":{"bankA":"1.2-15"},"assetId":"0000-0000-0000","lastSeen":"1637655821","bevent":{"event":"update"},"rssi":{"last":-69},"sensors":{"battery":83},"stats":{"uptime":"82350","frame_cnt":3},"vendorName":"Aruba"}]};
for (const beacon of newData.devices[0].beacons) {
    console.log(beacon);
}
```

[image: Image output]

Answer (score 1):

`arr1` is an Array it doesn't have `beacons` property. If you expect it to be the only one item with the mac you should use `data.find` instead of `data.filter`. Also do not use `for-in` loop to iterate over arrays. You can use `for-of` or `.forEach` instead.

```
const data = [
        {"mac":"f008d155b4fe","deviceClass":["iBeacon","eddystone"],"model":"iBeacon","lastSeen":"1637655820","bevent":{"event":"update"},"rssi":{"last":-84},"beacons":[{"ibeacon":{"uuid":"783a69707094d0863b4a9bf94e555241","major":816,"minor":6,"power":0},"eddystone":{"power":0}}],"sensors":{"temperatureC":18,"voltage":3.299999952316284},"stats":{"uptime":"710","adv_cnt":"24","frame_cnt":7}},
        {"mac":"a0e6f8515eff","deviceClass":["arubaTag"],"firmware":{"bankA":"1.2-15"},"assetId":"0000-0000-0000","lastSeen":"1637655821","bevent":{"event":"update"},"rssi":{"last":-69},"sensors":{"battery":83},"stats":{"uptime":"82350","frame_cnt":3},"vendorName":"Aruba"}
  ];
  
  // expecting only o1 
  const arr1 = data.find(d => d.mac == "f008d155b4fe");
  console.log('arr1', arr1);
  for (const beacon of arr1.beacons) { // use for-of or `forEach`
    console.log(beacon);
}
```